# Want to create a approval workflow from window phone 7

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, sharepoint-2010

we are integrating sharepoint 2010 with window phone 7.

we want to create a interface on phone using which we can create a approval workflow on sharepoint site.

Is there any inbuilt sharepoint web service available??

If not what other options we have....

if we try to create our own web service for this , than what should be the functionality of that web service

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad but, yes, SharePoint has [web services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms479390%28v=office.12%29.aspx).